# Find user hostname for local request between two applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've got two applications on a single server.
The first one is a simple asp.net and the second one is an asp.net web api.
Now I make a request from the simple asp.net application to the web api and I want to find out simple asp.net application host name (e.g. localhost) but HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName always returns UserHostAddress (user host IP).

Could anyone tell me where I can find user host name for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Not to discourage you, but I think it would be better to store the target hostname in an `appsetting`. In this case your applications are not bound to the server.

Comment: Actually I want to bound the clients applications with the web api and reject requests that are not in a white list of web api.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Request.Url.DnsSafeHost
```

this will bring you "localhost" or

you can add a key in appsetting in webconfig like below

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="app_name" value="yourApiProjectName" />
  </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

and use

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["app_name"]
```

to get the app name.

hope this helps..

Comment: Yeah but it's localhost with request url port. And I need smth like localhost:11111 calls localhost:22222 and the second one tells me that request comes from localhost:11111. Of course in production I'll have real domain names instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

As I've understood there is no simple way to get client's host. So I decided pass client's host through request header - referer.